# Safest way of use of PDO

Tags: php, sql

I'm a very "sketchy" person about security but I'm also a confusing person to understand when it comes to my logic of coding but.

What is the BEST absolute BEST method of doing prepared statements without having to bind every parameter and having to do anything else. Because in ADO I could simply do this

```
$stmt = $conn->execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = $user AND password = $pass");
```

And then I could easily collect the field this way.

```
$stmt->fields['UID'];
```

I don't know how to do this in PDO but if I'm going to move to PDO I'd rather do it securely.

And my friend suggested I make a sanitization function? How would I go about this and is there any pre-made PHP sanitization functions that would be useful?

Comment: You shouldn't need to sanitize the values if you are correctly using prepared statements. Gone are the days of `mysql_real_escape_string`

Comment: Would it be a smart idea to do both as well though?

Comment: If you're going to do that, you should just manually bind them. That way you can get type validation. `$stmt->bindParam(1, $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);`

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to manually bind each parameter one by one. This works:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($user, $pass));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo $row['UID'];
```

Comment: I made a clean function that takes advantage of filter_var and I made it so it sanitizes the input and using your technique. Is it a smart idea?